# discretization of exponential distribution

Tags: statistics

How do I show that  X~exp($\lambda$) if and only if $\hat{nX}$~geo(p) with $$p = P(X<\frac{1}{n}) = F_x(\frac{1}{n}) ? $$

I started by stating that $$\hat{nX} \sim  geo(e^\frac{-1}{\lambda n})$$
which gives us $$ P(X \leq \frac{1}{n})=1-e^\frac{-1}{\lambda n}$$

and then how do I go about stating that X is exponential with parameter $\lambda$

Comment: What does $\hat{nX}$ denote?

Comment: n would just be all natural numbers and I believe $$\hat{X} = [X] + 1 $$ where $$ X \sim exp(\lambda) $$

Answer (score 0):

$$nX=\frac{\lambda}{n}e^{\frac{-\lambda}{n}}$$
$$p=\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{n}}\lambda e^{-\lambda x}=1-e^{\frac{-\lambda}{n}}$$
$$nX=(1-p)(\frac{\lambda}{n})$$

However, from here I don't know how you want to get from this to your approximation.